# Оцените верстку  резинового макета

Tags: вёрстка

Доброе время суток, 
oцените, пожалуйста, верстку трех страниц
[page1](http://weburoki.com.ua/portfolio/bm-potolki/index.html)
[page2](http://weburoki.com.ua/portfolio/bm-potolki/page3.html)
[page3](http://weburoki.com.ua/portfolio/bm-potolki/page2.html)

Comment: м, это называется резиновая верстка? не заметил. Обычная фиксированная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) 2-ух
2) нельзя выделить и скопировать телефон
3) меню продукции в заднице. Спецпредложение должно пропадать, либо не быть таким большим. 
4) та же претензия к трем плашкам вверху. К тому же, они некликабельны. Ясно же, что "замер бесплатный при условии, что..."
"Профессиональный монтаж, который..."
"Гарантия с сотней ограничений". Хотелось бы иметь возможность это видеть. Иначе плашки бесполезны.
5) светло-оранжевые плашки на белом фоне... colorschemedesigner.com вам в помощь.
В общем, еще как-то потянет на газету, но как сайт - пользоваться неудобно.
Исключение - планшеты с высоким разрешением.Там и размер плашек более-менее оправдан, и вертикально растянутая информация пойдет для книжной ориентации.

Comment: Спасибо, учту!